# <form action = "./"> pra onde vai?

Tags: php, html, asp

Estou passando uma página ASP para PHP e encontrei um formulário em que o atributo action tinha o seguinte valor: *`<form action="./">`*. Esse valor do action funciona como um *`<form action="#">`*? Ou seja, direciona para a mesma página?

Comment: ./ significa diretorio atual.

Comment: http://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/caminho_absoluto_e_caminho_relativo.php#.WYsMt3Xytpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negativo, quando ele envia para `"./"` vai cair na raiz da pasta atual. Aí no caso, quem entra em cena e recebe os parâmetros do formulário será o index desta pasta.

A não ser, claro, que a página do formulário em questão já seja o index, aí volta para ela.

Answer (score 2):

Um action contendo "#" está fazendo referência a uma ancora presente na própria página. Como em:

```
<a href="#titulo">Link na pagina</a>
...
<a name="titulo"></a>
```

Quando se usa uma ancora sem nome como em "#" a maioria dos navegadores por default volta para o topo da página.

Quando você usa no href o valor "/" está apontando para a página de índice (index.html, index.php, index.aspx, ou conforme configurado no servidor) da raíz do site.

Quando você usa um href "./" está apontando para a index do diretório atual.

Quando você usa href "?qualquer_coisa", está fazendo referencia a página atual, atualizando ela com algum parâmetro via GET.

Answer (score 1):

Sem enrolar, significa ir para o diretorio atual.
Ou seja, se o diretorio da pagina `x.asp` for `c:\pages\files\x.asp`, irá para `c:\pages\files`